# Screen doesn't turn on sometimes, after dual boot installation

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot

I have Windows 8 and installed Ubuntu 13.10, as dual boot. After this installation, the screen doesn't turn on sometimes, even though the system loads normally in the background (I hear the welcoming sound of the OS). A hard reset is required in order for the screen to turn on.

These "sometimes", precisely, are:

- When I cold boot the computer.
- When I am running one of the OSs and I restart the computer, so I can load the other OS.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the Linux kernel you use (or the display driver on Linux) uses some weird quirk.
They do that to get hardware working, most of the times because there is no other way.

(Developer cannot figure out how it works, so he uses some "magic". Which on the other hand, messes up the standard behaviour of the hardware.)

**You could try installing Fedora if you are not a heavy Unity user.** (The interface of Ubuntu).
It uses a newer kernel, and gets updates more regurarly. There is no way to tell if it will fix your issue for sure, though. So it's not a definite solution.

**You can also try updating your kernel / gpu drivers.**
Ubuntu had a PPA of doing the former, but they discontinued it as it caused problems.
(You can still grab the kernel by hand and install it. Just Google "ubuntu kernel 3.12" for example.)
GPU update is do-able.

There are two PPAs for this.
- oibaf's PPA: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers/
- X-swat: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates

Oibaf's PPA is more stable, it's just a minor upgrade. Sometimes it already helps.
X-swat is newer, but also more risky. **Note: Both can break all GPU functionality.** They do not harm your hardware, but they may mess up your Linux installation any time.

Comment: Linux... always ready to mess up your system... always fun! :D

Comment: @Milkncookiez - Agreed. I spent many hours of my life to fix such issues. Linux is not free. On Windows, you pay money for the license, and a small portion of your time. On Mac, it's the same. There is no license fee on Linux, but you pay with huge chunks of time. Every single occasion eats up your life bit-by-bit. And that's never going to come back.